# How to estimate calcium concentration from fluorescence images

Tags: neuroimaging

Is there a way to get a rough estimate of a [Ca2+] based on fluorescence microscopy images (obtained using GCaMP for example)? Usually what we get is the ratio f/f0, but is there a way to estimate the absolute value of [Ca2+]? I found an [old paper on this subject](https://www.cell.com/action/showPdf?pii=S0006-3495%2800%2976809-3), but using their formula, there are still paramewters which I wouldn't know how to access experimentally.